# Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition

Tags: openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I am very new to openapi-generator and I could have missed the obvious.

I am trying to generate client and server stubs for a ["well known" REST API](https://docs.zerotier.com/openapi/centralv1.json).

I also validated the specs with [advised tool](https://apitools.dev/swagger-parser/online/) and it shows no errors/warnings.

OTOH running `openapi-generator-cli` shows multiple errors (full listing below) but manages to generate running code.

Said code seems unable to handle Authorization: `... Unsupported http authorization scheme token`.

Any hint on what's going wrong and how to fix problem would be welcome.

Here follows full transcript:

```
mcon@cinderella:~/web/zt$ wget https://docs.zerotier.com/openapi/centralv1.json
...

mcon@cinderella:~/web/zt$ ~/node_modules/.bin/openapi-generator-cli generate -i centralv1.json -g python-aiohttp -o tmp/server-aiohttp
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.DefaultGenerator - Generating with dryRun=false
[main] INFO  o.o.c.ignore.CodegenIgnoreProcessor - Output directory (/home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp) does not exist, or is inaccessible. No file (.openapi-generator-ignore) will be evaluated.
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.DefaultGenerator - OpenAPI Generator: python-aiohttp (server)
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.DefaultGenerator - Generator 'python-aiohttp' is considered stable.
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonCodegen - Environment variable PYTHON_POST_PROCESS_FILE not defined so the Python code may not be properly formatted. To define it, try 'export PYTHON_POST_PROCESS_FILE="/usr/local/bin/yapf -i"' (Linux/Mac)
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonCodegen - NOTE: To enable file post-processing, 'enablePostProcessFile' must be set to `true` (--enable-post-process-file for CLI).
[main] ERROR o.o.codegen.InlineModelResolver - Illegal schema found with $ref combined with other properties, no properties should be defined alongside a $ref:
 class ObjectSchema {
    class Schema {
        type: object
        format: null
        $ref: #/components/schemas/DNS
        description: null
        title: null
        multipleOf: null
        maximum: null
        exclusiveMaximum: null
        minimum: null
        exclusiveMinimum: null
        maxLength: null
        minLength: null
        pattern: null
        maxItems: null
        minItems: null
        uniqueItems: null
        maxProperties: null
        minProperties: null
        required: null
        not: null
        properties: null
        additionalProperties: null
        nullable: null
        readOnly: null
        writeOnly: null
        example: null
        externalDocs: null
        deprecated: null
        discriminator: null
        xml: null
    }
}
[main] ERROR o.o.codegen.InlineModelResolver - Illegal schema found with $ref combined with other properties, no properties should be defined alongside a $ref:
 class ObjectSchema {
    class Schema {
        type: object
        format: null
        $ref: #/components/schemas/DNS
        description: null
        title: null
        multipleOf: null
        maximum: null
        exclusiveMaximum: null
        minimum: null
        exclusiveMinimum: null
        maxLength: null
        minLength: null
        pattern: null
        maxItems: null
        minItems: null
        uniqueItems: null
        maxProperties: null
        minProperties: null
        required: null
        not: null
        properties: null
        additionalProperties: null
        nullable: null
        readOnly: null
        writeOnly: null
        example: null
        externalDocs: null
        deprecated: null
        discriminator: null
        xml: null
    }
}
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.InlineModelResolver - Inline schema created as MemberConfig_tags_inner_inner. To have complete control of the model name, set the `title` field or use the modelNameMapping option (e.g. --model-name-mappings MemberConfig_tags_inner_inner=NewModel,ModelA=NewModelA in CLI) or inlineSchemaNameMapping option (--inline-schema-name-mappings MemberConfig_tags_inner_inner=NewModel,ModelA=NewModelA in CLI).
[main] ERROR o.o.codegen.InlineModelResolver - Illegal schema found with $ref combined with other properties, no properties should be defined alongside a $ref:
 class ObjectSchema {
    class Schema {
        type: object
        format: null
        $ref: #/components/schemas/OrgSsoConfig
        description: null
        title: null
        multipleOf: null
        maximum: null
        exclusiveMaximum: null
        minimum: null
        exclusiveMinimum: null
        maxLength: null
        minLength: null
        pattern: null
        maxItems: null
        minItems: null
        uniqueItems: null
        maxProperties: null
        minProperties: null
        required: null
        not: null
        properties: null
        additionalProperties: null
        nullable: null
        readOnly: null
        writeOnly: null
        example: null
        externalDocs: null
        deprecated: null
        discriminator: null
        xml: null
    }
}
[main] ERROR o.o.codegen.InlineModelResolver - Illegal schema found with $ref combined with other properties, no properties should be defined alongside a $ref:
 class ObjectSchema {
    class Schema {
        type: object
        format: null
        $ref: #/components/schemas/OrgSsoConfig
        description: null
        title: null
        multipleOf: null
        maximum: null
        exclusiveMaximum: null
        minimum: null
        exclusiveMinimum: null
        maxLength: null
        minLength: null
        pattern: null
        maxItems: null
        minItems: null
        uniqueItems: null
        maxProperties: null
        minProperties: null
        required: null
        not: null
        properties: null
        additionalProperties: null
        nullable: null
        readOnly: null
        writeOnly: null
        example: null
        externalDocs: null
        deprecated: null
        discriminator: null
        xml: null
    }
}
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.InlineModelResolver - Inline schema created as Status_loginMethods. To have complete control of the model name, set the `title` field or use the modelNameMapping option (e.g. --model-name-mappings Status_loginMethods=NewModel,ModelA=NewModelA in CLI) or inlineSchemaNameMapping option (--inline-schema-name-mappings Status_loginMethods=NewModel,ModelA=NewModelA in CLI).
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Path '/network/{networkID}' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by '/network/{network_id}'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Parameter name 'networkID' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by 'network_id'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Parameter name 'networkID' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by 'network_id'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Parameter name 'networkID' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by 'network_id'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Path '/network/{networkID}/member' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by '/network/{network_id}/member'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Parameter name 'networkID' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by 'network_id'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Path '/network/{networkID}/member/{memberID}' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by '/network/{network_id}/member/{member_id}'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Parameter name 'networkID' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by 'network_id'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Parameter name 'memberID' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by 'member_id'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Parameter name 'networkID' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by 'network_id'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Parameter name 'memberID' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by 'member_id'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Parameter name 'networkID' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by 'network_id'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Parameter name 'memberID' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by 'member_id'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Path '/user/{userID}' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by '/user/{user_id}'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Parameter name 'userID' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by 'user_id'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Parameter name 'userID' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by 'user_id'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Parameter name 'userID' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by 'user_id'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Path '/user/{userID}/token' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by '/user/{user_id}/token'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Parameter name 'userID' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by 'user_id'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Path '/user/{userID}/token/{tokenName}' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by '/user/{user_id}/token/{token_name}'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Parameter name 'userID' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by 'user_id'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Parameter name 'tokenName' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by 'token_name'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Path '/org/{orgID}' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by '/org/{org_id}'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Parameter name 'orgID' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by 'org_id'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Path '/org/{orgID}/user' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by '/org/{org_id}/user'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Parameter name 'orgID' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by 'org_id'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Path '/org-invitation/{inviteID}' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by '/org-invitation/{invite_id}'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Parameter name 'inviteID' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by 'invite_id'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Parameter name 'inviteID' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by 'invite_id'
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Parameter name 'inviteID' is not consistent with Python variable names. It will be replaced by 'invite_id'
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.DefaultGenerator - Model PermissionsMap not generated since it's an alias to map (without property) and `generateAliasAsModel` is set to false (default)
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonCodegen - Codegen property is null (e.g. map/dict of undefined type). Default to typing.Any.
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonCodegen - Codegen property is null (e.g. map/dict of undefined type). Default to typing.Any.
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonCodegen - Codegen property is null (e.g. map/dict of undefined type). Default to typing.Any.
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonCodegen - Codegen property is null (e.g. map/dict of undefined type). Default to typing.Any.
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonCodegen - Codegen property is null (e.g. map/dict of undefined type). Default to typing.Any.
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonCodegen - Codegen property is null (e.g. map/dict of undefined type). Default to typing.Any.
[main] WARN  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonCodegen - Codegen property is null (e.g. map/dict of undefined type). Default to typing.Any.
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/api_token.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/auth_methods.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/dns.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/ip_range.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/ipv4_assign_mode.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/ipv6_assign_mode.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/invite_status.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/member.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/member_config.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/member_config_tags_inner_inner.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/network.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/network_config.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/network_sso_config.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/org_sso_config.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/organization.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/organization_invitation.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/organization_member.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/permissions.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/random_token.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/route.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/sso_issuer.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/status.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/status_login_methods.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/user.py
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/controllers/network_controller.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/tests/test_network_controller.py
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/controllers/network_member_controller.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/tests/test_network_member_controller.py
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/controllers/organizations_controller.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/tests/test_organizations_controller.py
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/controllers/user_controller.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/tests/test_user_controller.py
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/controllers/util_controller.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/tests/test_util_controller.py
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown scheme `token` found in the HTTP security definition.
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Path '/network/{network_id}' is not consistent with the original OpenAPI definition. It will be replaced back by '/network/{networkID}'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Reverting name of parameter 'network_id' of operation 'get_network_by_id' back to 'networkID'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Reverting name of parameter 'network_id' of operation 'update_network' back to 'networkID'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Reverting name of parameter 'network_id' of operation 'delete_network' back to 'networkID'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Path '/network/{network_id}/member' is not consistent with the original OpenAPI definition. It will be replaced back by '/network/{networkID}/member'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Reverting name of parameter 'network_id' of operation 'get_network_member_list' back to 'networkID'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Path '/network/{network_id}/member/{member_id}' is not consistent with the original OpenAPI definition. It will be replaced back by '/network/{networkID}/member/{memberID}'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Reverting name of parameter 'network_id' of operation 'get_network_member' back to 'networkID'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Reverting name of parameter 'member_id' of operation 'get_network_member' back to 'memberID'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Reverting name of parameter 'network_id' of operation 'update_network_member' back to 'networkID'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Reverting name of parameter 'member_id' of operation 'update_network_member' back to 'memberID'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Reverting name of parameter 'network_id' of operation 'delete_network_member' back to 'networkID'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Reverting name of parameter 'member_id' of operation 'delete_network_member' back to 'memberID'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Path '/org-invitation/{invite_id}' is not consistent with the original OpenAPI definition. It will be replaced back by '/org-invitation/{inviteID}'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Reverting name of parameter 'invite_id' of operation 'get_invitation_by_id' back to 'inviteID'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Reverting name of parameter 'invite_id' of operation 'accept_invitation' back to 'inviteID'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Reverting name of parameter 'invite_id' of operation 'decline_invitation' back to 'inviteID'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Path '/org/{org_id}' is not consistent with the original OpenAPI definition. It will be replaced back by '/org/{orgID}'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Reverting name of parameter 'org_id' of operation 'get_organization_by_id' back to 'orgID'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Path '/org/{org_id}/user' is not consistent with the original OpenAPI definition. It will be replaced back by '/org/{orgID}/user'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Reverting name of parameter 'org_id' of operation 'get_organization_members' back to 'orgID'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Path '/user/{user_id}' is not consistent with the original OpenAPI definition. It will be replaced back by '/user/{userID}'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Reverting name of parameter 'user_id' of operation 'get_user_by_id' back to 'userID'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Reverting name of parameter 'user_id' of operation 'update_user_by_id' back to 'userID'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Reverting name of parameter 'user_id' of operation 'delete_user_by_id' back to 'userID'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Path '/user/{user_id}/token' is not consistent with the original OpenAPI definition. It will be replaced back by '/user/{userID}/token'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Reverting name of parameter 'user_id' of operation 'add_api_token' back to 'userID'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Path '/user/{user_id}/token/{token_name}' is not consistent with the original OpenAPI definition. It will be replaced back by '/user/{userID}/token/{tokenName}'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Reverting name of parameter 'user_id' of operation 'delete_api_token' back to 'userID'
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.AbstractPythonConnexionServerCodegen - Reverting name of parameter 'token_name' of operation 'delete_api_token' back to 'tokenName'
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/README.md
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/test-requirements.txt
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/requirements.txt
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/__main__.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/util.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/typing_utils.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/controllers/__init__.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/controllers/security_controller.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/__init__.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/models/base_model.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/openapi/openapi.yaml
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/tests/conftest.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/tests/__init__.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/openapi_server/__init__.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/setup.py
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/tox.ini
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/.gitignore
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/.openapi-generator-ignore
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/.openapi-generator/VERSION
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/mcon/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp/.openapi-generator/FILES
################################################################################
# Thanks for using OpenAPI Generator.                                          #
# Please consider donation to help us maintain this project                  #
# https://opencollective.com/openapi_generator/donate                          #
################################################################################
mcon@cinderella:~/web/zt$ cd tmp/server-aiohttp
mcon@cinderella:~/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp$ python3 -m venv venv
mcon@cinderella:~/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp$ venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
...

mcon@cinderella:~/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp$ venv/bin/python -m openapi_server
... Unsupported http authorization scheme token
... Unsupported http authorization scheme token
... Unsupported http authorization scheme token
... Unsupported http authorization scheme token
... Unsupported http authorization scheme token
... Unsupported http authorization scheme token
... Unsupported http authorization scheme token
... Unsupported http authorization scheme token
... Unsupported http authorization scheme token
... Unsupported http authorization scheme token
... Unsupported http authorization scheme token
... Unsupported http authorization scheme token
... Unsupported http authorization scheme token
... Unsupported http authorization scheme token
... Unsupported http authorization scheme token
... Unsupported http authorization scheme token
... Unsupported http authorization scheme token
... Unsupported http authorization scheme token
... Unsupported http authorization scheme token
... Unsupported http authorization scheme token
... Unsupported http authorization scheme token
... Unsupported http authorization scheme token
... Unsupported http authorization scheme token
... Unsupported http authorization scheme token
======== Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080 ========
(Press CTRL+C to quit)
^C
mcon@cinderella:~/web/zt/tmp/server-aiohttp$ cat centralv1.json
```